# Hausdorff dimension of computable real numbers

Tags: computability, dimension-theory-analysis

This might be a trivial question but do the computable numbers have a positive Hausdorff dimension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**

The set of computable numbers is countable and every countable set (in the reals) has Hausdorff dimension $0$ (in a strong way).